# Cannot write log info in log file in Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a problem about generating log info when I work in Docker. There is no issue to write logs in log file in localhost.

I cannot see any new logs when I implement the CRUD process during docker.

How can I connect log file(**Springboot-Elk.log**) to Docker?

How can I fix it?

Here is the file showing screenshots : [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1T-10-pFJ5PLlrzoHy8t2IK_EcY6ZTPgt?usp=sharing)

Here is my project link : [My Project](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootElk)

Here is the **docker-compose.yml** shown below

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.15.2
    user: root
    command: -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/
    volumes:
      - ./elk/logstash/:/etc/logstash/conf.d/
      - ./Springboot-Elk.log:/tmp/logs/Springboot-Elk.log
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  filebeat:
    build:
      context: ./filebeat
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - "logstash:logstash"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/host_docker/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker:/host_docker/var/lib/docker
    depends_on:
      - logstash
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.15.2
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./elk/kibana/:/usr/share/kibana/config/
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    entrypoint: ["./bin/kibana", "--allow-root"]

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./elk/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
  app:
    image: 'springbootelk:latest'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: SpringBootElk
    depends_on:
      - db
      - logstash
    ports:
      - '8077:8077'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/springbootexample?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=springexample
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=111111
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3366:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

# Volumes
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Here is **logstash.conf** shown below

```
    input {
        beats {
                port => 5000
        }
        file {
                path => "/tmp/logs/Springboot-Elk.log"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
                start_position => "beginning"
        }
}
output {
        stdout{
                codec => rubydebug
        }
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                index => "dockerlogs"
        }
}
```

**filebeat.yml** file is shown below.

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: docker
    enabled: true
    containers:
      ids:
        - "*"
      path: "/host_docker/var/lib/docker/containers"


processors:
  - add_docker_metadata:
      host: "unix:///host_docker/docker.sock"

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash:5000"]

log files:
logging.level: info
logging.to_files: false
logging.to_syslog: false
loggins.metrice.enabled: false
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0644
ssl.verification_mode: none
```

Here is the **Dockerfile** of **filebeat.yml**

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.15.2

COPY filebeat.yml /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml

USER root
RUN mkdir /usr/share/filebeat/dockerlogs
RUN chown -R root /usr/share/filebeat/
RUN chmod -R go-w /usr/share/filebeat/
```

As I want to see logs in **logstash** , I run this command docker container logs -f .
I cannot see any logs defined in PersonController and PersonService there.
Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you define your use case clearly along with the question?

Comment: @JinnaBalu When I can implement CRUD operations, logs from Controller and Service cannot be added log file when I work with Docker. I couldn't where the problem in logstash, docker-compose.yml and filebeat. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer shown below.

After I revised logstash.conf file shown below, my issue was dissappeared.

```
input {
        tcp {
                port => 5000
        }
        beats {
                port => 5044
        }
        file {
                path => "/tmp/logs/Springboot-Elk.log"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
                start_position => "beginning"
        }
}
output {
        stdout{
                codec => rubydebug
        }
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                index => "dockerlogs"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with docker, its good to write all logs to the console. This will allow it to expose logs when run in Kubernetes or other ochestrators. On spring framework, you can achieve this by changing to ConsoleAppender. The example bellow shows how to achieve this in log4j.xml. Place the file to your resources folder and add the log4j dependencies(Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging ):

```
<configuration>
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="com.yourcompany.packagename" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
</logger>
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

You can still configure log to disk by adding another appender in the configuration above, but you need to add a mount point to your docker-compose file to point to the logs directory on your application.

It is good to note that Docker is stateless and therefore logs are lost when you restart the container.

Comment: I updated my repository to use log4j but I still cannot see logs

Comment: Once you use console appender you can use ```docker container logs container-id -f``` to view container logs.

Comment: I used it but I cannot see any logs coming from Controller and Service. I just share its screenshot in the post.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct logger in your code.

Comment: Is it possible to look through my logstash.conf and docker-compose.yml if you don't mind?

Comment: From your sample code I see you are using logback.xml instead of log4j.xml this will not work well with sl4j.

Comment: I updated my repository but it still didn't work after I also add filebeat in logstash. How can I fix it?

Comment: We can connect on this if needed, but let me go through your repository

Answer (score 0):

For me it works. But my ELK Stack is running not in docker.

This is my logstash config (same config for TCP and UDP):

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5144
        codec => "json"
        type => "logback"
    }

    udp {
        port => 5144
        codec => "json"
        type => "logback"
    }
}

output {
    if [type]=="logback" {
         elasticsearch {
             hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
             index => "logback-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

And you have to setup the logback index in Kibana too.

This is my logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <springProperty name="mvnVersion" source="info.app.version"/>
    <springProperty name="appName" source="info.app.name"/>
    <springProperty name="tcpLogHost" source="logstash.tcpHost"/>
    <springProperty name="udpLogHost" source="logstash.udpHost"/>
    <springProperty name="udpLogPort" source="logstash.udpPort"/>

    <appender name="stashUdp" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashUdpSocketAppender">
        <host>${udpLogHost}</host>
        <port>${udpLogPort}</port>
        <layout class="net.logstash.logback.layout.LogstashLayout">
            <customFields>{"appName":"${appName}","env":"${env}","mvnVersion":"${mvnVersion}"}</customFields>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{100} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="stashUdp" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I'm logging directly (UDP) to ELK Stack.

And you need

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    <version>${logstash.logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it works with Docker.

Comment: I updated my repository but it still didn't work after I also add filebeat in logstash. How can I fix it?

Comment: The link was already defined in the post.

Comment: I updated my repository but it still didn't work. Is it possible to run my App?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it. I tested your code with PostgreSQL and my log config. It work's fine and I see the logs in my ELK Stack. Here https://drive.google.com/file/d/10TLXcMxCXAnDhoBdG25UmxTKJYE94HFR/view?usp=sharing is the changed code.  But to test my config you need this stackoverflow.com/a/71892197/6284144 logstash config. And than you have to create the new logback index in Kibana. Without this, you will see nothing.

Comment: I cannot see logs appearing when I work with Docker. These logs were coming from previous logs when I worked with localhost.

Comment: I updated my repository. I forgot to say it.

Comment: Start only your ELK Stack Docker and than start the app outside of the docker. To see what happens. I can't check your docker configration, cause I'm using ELK Stack as single instance. Or you try this https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

Comment: As you couldn't look through it, do you think how I fix it? I need what I fix my issue.

Comment: Where is the problem? Even i I defined filebeat connecting with logstash, I cannot see logs when I work with Docker. Is it possible to look through docker codes if you don't mind?

Comment: For your test case you don't need filebeat. You need filebeat, when the logs should be parsed by filebeat and sendet to logstash. This ./Springboot-Elk.log:/tmp/logs/Springboot-Elk.log volume in logstash is wrong. Cause logstash is not parsing the external logs.

You have to go step by step: 1. Activate logging for every elk component 2. Connect to the docker image and check the logs 3. Sending logs (like in my changes) directly to logstash (without filebeat)and see what happens. When I find some time, than I can take a look on this. But not at the moment. 4) Add filebeat.

Comment: Your problem ist, that you don't know a lot about Docker and Elk Stack.

Comment: What's wrong in docker-compose? I already connected all components in docker-compose? How can I define log in the volume of logstash? I edited my post to show some screenshots. I hope you can look through it.

Comment: For me it's not clear what you want to do. You configured logstash to read input from Springboot-Elk.log. In this case you don't need filebeat. As I wrote, I prefer send the logs as json directly over TCP/UDP from the microservice to logstash. If you will use your configuration than filebat should read Springboot-Elk.log and send it to logstash. I think, this is your problem. Cause you wrote: "I updated my repository but it still didn't work after I also add filebeat in logstash."

Answer (score 0):

According to your repository you have `logback` configuration for logging, but excuded `logback` and added `log4j` support in your maven dependencies. To make `logback` work you just need not to exclude default logging library, and add newer version of the `logback` dependency (because specified by spring boot dependency version of logback doesn't contain specified in your configuration logstash appender - net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender).
F.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spingbootelk</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>main</name>
    <description>The usage of ELK in Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But it is better to find a good guide on the internet how to setup logging of your spring boot application to logstash properly. And I don't suggest you to use configuration in your repository for production purposes.